# How do i block direct access to th controller in codeigniter?

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, codeigniter-3

I am doing a project with angularJS and Codeginiter, Now i want to redirect URL to 404 page when a user access controller directly,

Any help appreciated

Comment: on angular i am using ui-route so when i made clean URL on angular then URL is working fine but when make refresh page, request going to the controller directly and loading data, how can i resolve this issue ?

Comment: Read the manual:  https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can make this by using routes. I mean you can redirect 404 method.

For example;

**lets say here is your Error controllers has 404 method**

```
class **Error** extends CI_Controllers(){

public function ci_404(){
}

}
```

**lets say here is your controllers you don't want to direct access**

```
class **MyController** extends CI_Controllers(){

public function index(){
}

}
```

**Your routes should be like;**

```
$route["mycontroller"] = "error/ci_404";
```